# Memory requirement for PCA/kPCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Is there a way to know exactly how much memory I will need to do PCA/kPCA in Python?

For example, if I have a matrix of N rows and M columns:

- What memory will I need if N = 100, 10000, 100000?
- And does M have an effect on the memory needed for PCA/kPCA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. From what I can glean from the paper *Online principal component analysis in high dimension; which algorithm to choose?* by [Cardot & Degras (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03688) the complexity of PCA depends on the SVD (singular value deomposition) step. Thus, the [space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) of 'batch' (in memory) PCA is, using your notation, at least *O(NM)* for the data, plus *O(M<sup>2</sup>)* for the covariance matrix, so the complexity is *O(M<sup>2</sup>)* in total.

This is all backed up by [this tutorial paper by Li et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.12085). (Note that your *N* is their *m* and your *M* is their *n*.) They give more detail though, showing that about 3 copies are made of each matrix, and they show how the choice of algorithm matters.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50381112/3381305) to a question about NumPy's SVD implementation might help you compute the exact memory footprint of the process. Or check out a tool like [`memory-profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), which will also give you an exact answer.

**In short, the memory required depends on the algorithm but is very roughly 3 × (*NM* + *M*<sup>2</sup>). You can assume that each float in those arrays needs 8 bytes of memory.**